# pandas how to populate missing rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like:

```
Dept, Date, Number
dept1, 2020-01-01, 12
dept1, 2020-01-03, 34
dept2, 2020-01-03, 56
dept3, 2020-01-03, 78
dept2, 2020-01-04, 11
dept3, 2020-01-04, 12
...
```

eg, I want to fill zero for missing dept2 & dept3 on date 2020-01-01

```
Dept, Date, Number
dept1, 2020-01-01, 12
dept2, 2020-01-01, 0   <--need to be added 
dept3, 2020-01-01, 0   <--need to be added
dept1, 2020-01-03, 34
dept2, 2020-01-03, 56
dept3, 2020-01-03, 78
dept1, 2020-01-04, 0  <--need to be added
dept2, 2020-01-04, 11
dept3, 2020-01-04, 12
```

In other words, for unique dept, I need them to be shown on every unique date.

Is it a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/), to abstract the process, simply pass the columns that you wish to *expand*:

```
In [598]: df.complete('Dept', 'Date').fillna(0)
Out[598]: 
    Dept       Date  Number
0  dept1 2020-01-01    12.0
1  dept1 2020-01-03    34.0
2  dept1 2020-01-04     0.0
3  dept2 2020-01-01     0.0
4  dept2 2020-01-03    56.0
5  dept2 2020-01-04    11.0
6  dept3 2020-01-01     0.0
7  dept3 2020-01-03    78.0
8  dept3 2020-01-04    12.0
```

You could also stick solely to Pandas and use the [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method; [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) covers cases where the index is not unique, or there are nulls; it is an abstraction/convenience wrapper:

```
(df
 .set_index(['Dept', 'Date'])
 .pipe(lambda df: df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels), 
                             fill_value = 0))
 .reset_index()
 )
 
    Dept       Date  Number
0  dept1 2020-01-01      12
1  dept1 2020-01-03      34
2  dept1 2020-01-04       0
3  dept2 2020-01-01       0
4  dept2 2020-01-03      56
5  dept2 2020-01-04      11
6  dept3 2020-01-01       0
7  dept3 2020-01-03      78
8  dept3 2020-01-04      12
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `pivot` then `stack`

```
out = df.pivot(*df.columns).fillna(0).stack().reset_index(name='Number')
    Dept         Date  Number
0  dept1   2020-01-01    12.0
1  dept1   2020-01-03    34.0
2  dept1   2020-01-04     0.0
3  dept2   2020-01-01     0.0
4  dept2   2020-01-03    56.0
5  dept2   2020-01-04    11.0
6  dept3   2020-01-01     0.0
7  dept3   2020-01-03    78.0
8  dept3   2020-01-04    12.0
```

Comment: Thanks, how about when I have more columns like Product1_number, Product2_number, ...? it looks like pivot takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments.